# Change BehaviorSubject value in ngOnInit causing stack over flow error

Tags: angular, typescript, authentication, angular7

I am trying to change a Observable value in the service to get it on the other pages. Checking the value of user role and if the page is secure user should be redirected to the home page.

```
this.myservice.castrole.subscribe(value => {
    if (value === 'User') {
      this.rout.params.subscribe(params => {
        this.exid = params['examid'];
      });
    } else {
      this.myservice.checkUser('NoUser');
      this.router.navigate(['']);
    }
  });
```

I also tried to put this code in ngOnChanges but still same error is coming. It halts the browser for few seconds. In service the code is

```
private role = new BehaviorSubject<string>('NoUser');
  castrole = this.role.asObservable();
```

and

```
checkUser(data) {
  this.role.next(data);
}
```

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure your value castrole is not correctly accessible or null.

What I usually do for clarity is the following (in the service):

```
private roleSubject: BehaviorSubject<string> = new BehaviorSubject<string>('NoUser');

getRoleSubject() { 
   return this.roleSubject;
}

getRoleSubjectAsObservable() {
   return this.roleSubject.asObservable();
}
```

in any place where you need it:

Subject:

```
this.service.getRoleSubject().next(value);
```

Observable

```
this.service.getRoleSubjectAsObservable().subscribe(value => { ... });
```